# Grails 3.3.1 - Enum field in gorm domain that uses alternate value

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

In the domain, I have:

```
class PetShop{
  ...
  DogType dog
}
```

I have an enum:

```
enum DogType {
    POODLE('Poodle', 'p'),
    BEAGLE('BEAGLE', 'b'),
    ...

    private final String prettyValue
    private final String dbValue

    public String getPrettyValue() {
        return this.prettyValue
    }

    public String getDBValue() {
        return this.dbValue
    }

    DogType(String prettyValue, String dbValue) {
        this.prettyValue = prettyValue
        this.dbValue = dbValue
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.dbValue
    }
}
```

I want to save the value of "dbValue" to the variable "dog" in the database, e.g. "p" and not "POODLE" or 1. How can I do this?

Comment: then reverse the two and switch the two around and set     dog enumType: "ordinal", sqlType: "String" since it is still a String but it will then map the first value aka what you want  POODLE( 'p', 'Poodle'), DogType(String dbValue, String prettyValue) {

Comment: I tried this, and it stored the string "0" instead of "p". If it makes a difference, I'm using SQL Server and used "sqlType: varchar(2)" instead.